# How to aggregate four upstream ports in the network module?

Tags: networking, sdn

Using SuperMicro network module, which related to Intel SDN product,
[the command PDF](https://www.supermicro.org.cn/manuals/other/Command_Line_Reference_SMCI_Rev_1.2.pdf) . and the [Web GUI manual](https://www.supermicro.org.cn/manuals/microblade/WebUI_Guide_MicroBlade.pdf).

there I have `qe57`, `qe61`, `qe65`, `qe69` four upstream ports, I want to aggregate them. how to do with it?

---

**EDIT-01**

I in the `qe57`, I add port to channel-group, get error:

```
192.168.200.1 (config-if qe57)#channel-group 3800 aggregation multiple

Error! Param1


192.168.200.1 (config-if qe57)#channel-group 3800 mode active

Error! Param1
```

Comment: The term you're looking for in that manual is `channel-group`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the manual you've linked, check page 206:

> **channel-group**
>
> The group of channel-group commands allows configuring Etherchannel/port bundling. After port is assigned to channel-group, all configuration for this port is cleared, e.g.: it is removed from participation in any Vlans, and static MAC definitions are removed. LAG configuration is applied for participated port.
>
> **Command Syntax**
>
> channel-group  {aggregation {individual | multiple}| mode active|passive}| {lacp port-priority }| timeout {short|long}| key | collecting| defaulting| distributing| expired| synchronization| partner key | partner number | partner priority | partner system

Comment: Hi， friend, check my post, I can not in the qe57 to add into channel-group 3800.

Comment: You should recheck the syntax. It doesn't match the docs and I've got no hardware to test with.